# firestore js multiple orderBy not sorting result

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a query containing 2 orderBy following by a startAt (that  applies a filter on the 1st orderBy (orderId)):

```js
  let result = await db    // db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('/orders')
    .where('userId', '==', userId) // userId = 'zHJgWUFL54deq4a...'
    .orderBy('orderId')
    .orderBy('co', 'desc')
    .startAt(filter)      // filter = '2020-01-YND'
    .get()
```

**Orders collection**:

```
// Item 1
{
  "co": 0,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDKALCK"
}

// Item 2
{
  "co": 1,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDSCSAD"
}
```

- Composite indexes created:

```
orders      userId Ascending orderId Ascending co Descending    Collection      Enabled
```

**RESULT**: result is not sorted (descending) by **co**.

```
// Item 1
{
  "co": 0,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDKALCK"
}

// Item 2
{
  "co": 1,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDSCSAD"
}

Instead of Item 2 first then Item 1
```

I've created an issue in firestore's github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2577) and will do the update here and there when I get an answer.

Thank you

## -----------------------------------------------------

**Update:**

Unfortunately, the problem with switching orderBy is that I get no result... I've already created the composite index.
filter is used to "search" orderId (search text, not full-text searching since it's not supported).

So these 2 queries return [] :

```
// changed orderBy order
 let result = await db    // db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('/orders')
    .where('userId', '==', userId) // userId = 'zHJgWUFL54deq4a...'
    .orderBy('co', 'desc')
    .orderBy('orderId')
    .startAt(filter)      // filter = '2020-01-YND'
    .get()

and: 

// added endAt
 let result = await db    // db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('/orders')
    .where('userId', '==', userId) // userId = 'zHJgWUFL54deq4a...'
    .orderBy('co', 'desc')
    .orderBy('orderId')
    .startAt(filter)      // filter = '2020-01-YND'
    .endAt(filter + '\uf8ff')
    .get()
```

But, if I remove orderBy('co', 'desc'), I got results but still not what I'm looking for:

```
 let result = await db    // db = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('/orders')
    .where('userId', '==', userId) // userId = 'zHJgWUFL54deq4a...'
    .orderBy('orderId')
    .startAt(filter)      // filter = '2020-01-YND'
    .endAt(filter + '\uf8ff')
    .get()

returns:
// Item 1
{
  "co": 0,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDKALCK"
}

// Item 2
{
  "co": 1,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDSCSAD"
}
```

Comment: Show us how your index looks like and please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood your question, I think you have probably not noted that when you order by multiple fields, the documents are ordered following the order of the `orderBy()`s in the methods chain.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=0):

> You can also order by multiple fields. For example, if you wanted to
>   order by state, and within each state order by population in
>   descending order:
>
> ```
>   let byStateByPop = citiesRef.orderBy('state').orderBy('population', 'desc');
> ```

In other words, in your case, the results are first ordered by `orderId` and then, **within each** `orderId` they are ordered by `co`.

---

So, your result below is correct, since `2020-01-YNDKALCK` is before `2020-01-YNDSCSAD`:

```
// Item 1
{
  "co": 0,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDKALCK"
}

// Item 2
{
  "co": 1,
  "userId": "zHJgWUFL54deq4a...",
  "orderId": "2020-01-YNDSCSAD"
}
```

You should try with records that share the same `orderId` value.

If you want the results to be first ordered by `co`, just swap the `orderBy()` (and build the new index).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still not working (updated my Question)